# Anyone know the manufacturer of this automotive connector?

Tags: identification, connector, automotive

This connector is part of a plug and socket used near the rear doors on the Tesla Model Y vehicle. I want to make a breakout harness for troubleshooting by plugging my cable in-line.

Ideally, I'd like the manufacturer and part number of both plug and socket so I can purchase a few to build up my breakout cable.

There are no noticeable manufacturer or part markings.

I've tried the Google Images search and came up with no hits. I even cropped the image to remove unnecessary information, but that didn't help the search much.

I've written to Digi-Key and Mouser, but no response from them.

I found [this connector](https://m.globalsources.com/Automotive-connector/Automotive-connector-1154668249p.htm) that seems sort of close, but not a match. It has a few blade pins for power as the connector I'm searching.

[image]

Comment: Are there no logos or other markings on the body of the connector?

Comment: Sorry, none that I can find. That would make it easy, right.

Comment: Most likely it is a custom connector defined by Tesla so whoever manufacturers it will only be able to sell it to Tesla. So most likely no distributor won't know anything about it or have it on sale. Even if it is a standard connector, unless you are going to buy thousands, finding a connector will cost them more in salaries than what they make when you buy a few connectors.

Comment: @Justme - yep I tend to agree with you, but asked anyway out of desperation.

Comment: For Automotive Connectors I ask these guys: https://connectorexperts.com/

Comment: @icodeplenty it is possible that there are very small markings on the connector ... the marking could easily be 0.5 mm in height ... look between the pins and everywhere else

Comment: Find a scrapped one and source those - unless someone got there before you !

Comment: Thanks Davide Andrea for the tip, I'll give them a try.

Comment: Ford engineer: "I need 15 data and 10 power lines. This standard 2x14 pin connector should do the trick". Tesla engineer: "Tell those guys in connector department I need a connector with 15 data and 10 power lines. In black... no, in white would be prettier"

Comment: Thanks Davide Andrea for that link, looks like this might be the right one: https://connectorexperts.com/i-31643419-cet2502.html?ref=category:1261639